# $_SESSION cookies not expiring when browser is closed

Tags: php, session, jquery-mobile, cookies

So here is my code that sends an expire time of a year if remember me is clicked.
And if not, then it sets the    session_set_cookie_params() to 0. Which means that it should destroy the session when browser is closed. However it isn't working like that for some reason.

This is my login page:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    if (($_POST['username'] == $user) && ($_POST['password'] == $pass)) {

    if (isset($_POST['rememberme'])) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['start'] = time();
        $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (60*60*24*365);
}
    else{
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
        session_set_cookie_params(0);
    }
    header('Location: index.php');

} else {
    $p->addContent('<font color = red>Wrong</font>');
}
}
```

This is my index page:

```
session_start();


if (isset($_POST['rememberme'])){
    $user = $_SESSION['username'];

}
else {
    $user = $_SESSION['username'];
    session_set_cookie_params(0);
}

if ($user == null) {
    $user = 'Guest';
    $logout = $p->header()->addButton('Login', 'login.php', 'a', 'home', false, false, true);
    $logout->rel('external');
}   
else{
    $logout = $p->header()->addButton('Logout', 'logout.php', 'a', 'delete', false, false, true);
    $logout->rel('external');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple. `session_set_cookie_params(0);` isn't affecting your session as you call it after calling `session_start();`.

Just reorder your code to something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if (($_POST['username'] == $user) && ($_POST['password'] == $pass)) {
        if (isset($_POST['rememberme'])) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['start'] = time();
            $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (60*60*24*365);
        } else {
            session_set_cookie_params(0);
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
        }
    header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        session_start();
        $p->addContent('<font color = red>Wrong</font>');
    }
} else {
    session_start();
}
```

EDIT:

It's also worth nothing that `session_set_cookie_params` only work on the current script and has to be called again every time you use `session_start()`. It might me useful to set a cookie to indicate if it should used.

Comment: darn, i thought this would work. It looked right to me haha. I closed out of my browser, went back to index.php but the session was still running. :/ pretty much stuck here.

Answer (score 2):

As of your code, `session_set_cookie_params()` isn't called in any case. Therefore I propose to do this:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
...
```

Note, that's actually useful to call `session_set_cookie_params()` always for session cookies.

> **Generate a new session-ID at each user level change**

To protect your applications against attackers, it is absolutely required to change the sessionID after each change of the role of a user:

- Anonymous user -> Logged in user
- Logged in user -> anonymous user
- Logged in user -> Administrative logged in user
- ...

Thus, if user gets logged in or logged off, please **regenerate the session ID** like so:

```
session_regenerate_id( true );
```

Have a look in [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/)'s [PHP security cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet).

**Session-files get deleted regularly**

Using PHP's standard session policy, sessions get mapped to regular files, so called session-files. If the user closes his browser, the session-file keeps living in the file system. Quite likely, the **operation system is going to delete the session-file once a day** (by night).

Thus, if a user comes back a day later, the sessionID cookie points to a **session-file, which might no longer be available**.

**The case of public PCs**

Additionally imagine a browser running on a public PC: If user closes his browser and a new user logs in, the other **user gets automatically logged** in.

Comment: wouldn't that set the session to close on browser exit for all cases. I don't want that. I want it to only be set to 0 for when remember me is not clicked.

Comment: Thanks so much for all of this, it wasn't necessary. But i will have a read through that :).

Comment: @AnujHari You are welcome! The PHP security cheat sheet is valuable reading!